# How to add continuous running code into nodejs postgresql client?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm stuck on a problem of wiring some logic into a nodejs pg client, the main logic has two part, the first one is connect to postgres server and getting some notification, it is as the following:

```
var rules = {}                // a rules object we are monitoring...
const pg_cli = new Client({
    ....
})

pg_cli.connect()
pg_cli.query('LISTEN zone_rules') // listen to the zone_rules channel

pg_cli.on('notification', msg => {
   rules = msg.payload
})
```

This part is easy and run without any issue, now what I'm trying to implement is to have another  function keeps monitoring the rules, and when an object is received and put into the rules, the function start accumulating the time the object stays in the rules (which may be deleted with another notification from pg server), and the monitoring function would send alert to another server if the duration of the object passed a certain time. I tried to wrote the code in the following style:

```
function check() {
  // watch and time accumulating code...
  process.nextTick(check)
}

check()
```

But I found the onevent code of getting notification then didn't have a chance to run! Does anybody have any idea about my problem. Or should I doing it in another way?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found change the nextTick to setImmediate solve the problem.